# In stats::glm(), why is the subset argument giving different results from when I subset the data argument myself?

Tags: r

Consider the following code:

```
library(ISLR)

row_list <- structure(list(`1` = 1:40, `2` = 41:79, `3` = 80:118, `4` = 119:157, 
               `5` = 158:196, `6` = 197:235, `7` = 236:274, `8` = 275:313, 
               `9` = 314:352, `10` = 353:392), 
          .Names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
test <- row_list[[1]]
train <- setdiff(unlist(row_list), row_list[[1]])
```

## Output 1:

```
> glm(mpg ~ poly(horsepower, 1), data = Auto, subset = train)

Call:  glm(formula = mpg ~ poly(horsepower, 1), data = Auto, subset = train)

Coefficients:
        (Intercept)  poly(horsepower, 1)  
              23.37              -133.05  

Degrees of Freedom: 351 Total (i.e. Null);  350 Residual
Null Deviance:      21460 
Residual Deviance: 8421     AIC: 2122
```

## Output 2:

```
> glm(mpg ~ poly(horsepower, 1), data = Auto[train,])

Call:  glm(formula = mpg ~ poly(horsepower, 1), data = Auto[train, ])

Coefficients:
        (Intercept)  poly(horsepower, 1)  
              24.05              -114.19  

Degrees of Freedom: 351 Total (i.e. Null);  350 Residual
Null Deviance:      21460 
Residual Deviance: 8421     AIC: 2122
```

As it can be seen above, the `(Intercept)` and `poly(horsepower, 1)` values differ between the two outputs. Why is this?

At least for `lm()`, *Introduction to Statistical Learning* suggests (see p. 191) that row indices can be used in the `subset` argument. Is this not the case for `glm()`, or is `subset` just not being used correctly?

Comment: One thing to note is that the fitted values are the same. It is only the parameterization that differs.  `fit1 <- fitted(glm(...)); fit2 <- fitted(glm(...)); all.equal(fit1, fit2)`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Thank you for pointing this out!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is to do with how the orthogonal polynomials are constructed by `poly`.

In the first example, they are constructed before subsetting, and in the second the subsetting takes place first (as you pass the subsetted data to `glm`).

Using raw polynomials gives identical results:

```
coef(glm(mpg~poly(hp,1),data=mtcars,subset=10:32))
(Intercept) poly(hp, 1) 
   20.63307   -28.66876 
coef(glm(mpg~poly(hp,1),data=mtcars[10:32,]))
(Intercept) poly(hp, 1) 
   19.93043   -25.43935 
coef(glm(mpg~poly(hp,1,raw=TRUE),data=mtcars,subset=10:32))
            (Intercept) poly(hp, 1, raw = TRUE) 
            31.64927851             -0.07509986 
coef(glm(mpg~poly(hp,1,raw=TRUE),data=mtcars[10:32,]))
            (Intercept) poly(hp, 1, raw = TRUE) 
            31.64927851             -0.07509986
```

Comment: How fascinating. It looks like I'll have to follow up on this in Stats SE. Thank you!