# Passing an additional argument through boot::boot()

Tags: r

MWE:

```
library(boot)
calculate_coeffs <- function(data, index){
  return( coef(lm(mpg~hp, data = data, subset = index)) )
}
boot(data = mtcars, statistic = calculate_coeffs, R = 1000)


ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP


Call:
boot(data = mtcars, statistic = calculate_coeffs, R = 1000)


Bootstrap Statistics :
       original       bias    std. error
t1* 30.09886054  0.204255101  2.13998077
t2* -0.06822828 -0.002014834  0.01418847
```

I would like to pass the `formula`, currently `mpg~hp`, as an argument of `boot()`.

In `?boot::boot`,

> Any further arguments can be passed to `statistic` through the ...
>   argument.

So I thought, let's try this:

```
library(boot)
calculate_coeffs <- function(data, index){
  return( coef(lm(formula, data = data, subset = index)) )
}
boot(data = mtcars, statistic = calculate_coeffs, R = 1000, formula = mpg~hp)

Error in statistic(data, original, ...) : 
  unused argument (formula = mpg ~ hp)
```

And then I thought, let's put this in one of the arguments for `calculate_coeffs`:

```
library(boot)
calculate_coeffs <- function(data, index, formula){
  return( coef(lm(formula, data = data, subset = index)) )
}
boot(data = mtcars, statistic = calculate_coeffs, R = 1000, formula = mpg~hp)

 Error in eval(substitute(subset), data, env) : object 'index' not found
```

For some reason, the examples at https://www.statmethods.net/advstats/bootstrapping.html do not have the same problem that I'm having - and they all work fine for me.

Comment: If you do `data = data[index,]` instead of using the `subset` argument, it seems to work.

Comment: @joran Wow. This `subset` argument seems to be more trouble than it's worth. I've learned a bit about the oddities of using this particular argument recently, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939063/in-statsglm-why-is-the-subset-argument-giving-different-results-from-when-i.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39348562/why-subset-doesnt-mind-missing-subset-argument-for-dataframes/39348718) on `subset`might also be of interest, though the issue in it relates more to object-oriented behavior and methods.